# Rewrite rule for redirecting from one directory to another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect pages from:

```
www.example.com/docs/buttons
www.example.com/docs/forms
```

to

```
www.example.com/components/buttons
www.example.com/components/buttons
```

My Rewrite rule is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^docs/(.*)$ /components/$1 [L]
```

The redirect works when I visit this URL:
`www.example.com/docs` and it redirects to `www.example.com/components`

but not when I visit this:
`www.example.com/docs/buttons`. Visiting this link gives me a 404

Could you please tell me whats wrong?

EDIT:

Answers to some of the questions asked below:

1. I just noticed that there are 2 places that i can write the redirect rules at:

   a. A config in the /etc/apache2 folder

   b. A .htaccess where my actual site is at /var/www/project
2. buttons is not a directory. There is a file called buttons.html in the docs folder and now in the new components folder

Comment: What happens when you visit `/docs/buttons`

Comment: It gives me a 404

Comment: are you putting a trailing / after buttons? does that make a difference? Also is it a real directory?

Comment: replied to your questions in the post. thanks! @PanamaJack

Comment: replied to your questions in the post. thanks! @anubhava

Comment: Can you show your full .htaccess from `/var/www/project`. Do you have a .htaccess inside docs/ also?

Comment: No. no .htaccess inside docs/. BTW I solved the issue. I had to write the rule in both /etc/apache/config and /var/www/project/.htaccess and it worked

Comment: Do you want the user to see the new URL? If so, you need the `R` flag.